# How to script database inserts with python?

Tags: python, mysql

Using old example:

```
 csr = con.cursor()
 csr.execute('Truncate table test.data')
 csr.executemany('INSERT INTO test.data VALUES (?,?,?,?)', Newdata)
 con.commit()
```

How would I insert %s into

```
csr.executemany('INSERT INTO test.data VALUES (?,?,?,?)', Newdata)
```

tried:

```
csr.executemany('INSERT INTO test.%s VALUES (?,?,?,?)', Newdata) % symbol
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
csr.executemany('INSERT INTO test.%s VALUES (?,?,?,?)' % symbol, Newdata)
```

Although I would instead do something like:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO test.%s VALUES (?,?,?,?)' % symbol
csr.executemany(query, Newdata)
```

Note that `?` is not the default placeholder on all database wrappers. In some `%s` is used instead (mysqldb, psycopg2 for instance). In these cases, It's sometimes simpler to build the query in parts.

Doing:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO test.%s' % symbol
query += ' VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)'
```

otherwise you would need something like:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO test.%s VALUES (%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s)' % symbol
```

which is a pain.